# Reading PNG binary data in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html

```
            var uint8 = new Uint8Array(plaintext);
            var arrayBuffer = uint8.buffer;
            var blob        = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
        var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(){
              var dataURL = reader.result;
              console.log('DATAURL');
              console.log(dataURL);
            };
            reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
```

plaintext - is  a png binary data, the problem is that dataURL comes empty am I do everything right in the code, or the problem may be in the binary data itself?

Comment: you may have some problem with your `plaintext`, could you show us how you got that? But at least, `dataURL` won't return a `dataURI`, but a `binaryString`, which makes your whole process pointless. What you need is `reader.readAsDataURL(blob)`

Comment: `new Blob([plaintext]);` seems more appropos

Comment: Also, you'll need to add the `{type:'image/png'}` to your Blob constructor